# The touchpad stops working after a while. How to fix it?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad

So I've got an HP Probook 440 G6 laptop. Ubuntu 18.04 is installed. After 2-3 days uptime touchpad stops responding while using laptop. The touchpad is Synaptic. Reboot fixes the issue, closing and opening the laptop lid is also fixing it. But how can I fix it permanently? Find the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` below.

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=8265 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA3082:00 06CB:8265 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA3082:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-SYNA3082:00/0018:06CB:8265.0002/input/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event16 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Model Probook 440 G6. And i have the same bug in WINDOWS.
A colegue of me has this too. So this might be a firmware bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Thomas. I think I figured out what was causing the problem. It was the static that was present in the office and where the issues were observed. Whenever I was home, everything was perfectly working. So the solution to this may be an application of proper grounding. Maybe an anti-static floor mat.